# iPhone not recognized by iTunes after not ejecting properly

Tags: iphone, windows

I unplugged my iPhone without clicking the eject button. Now the computer doesn't recognize it in iTunes.

I have followed everything in the help section but still no luck.

Comment: What "help steps" did you follow?  We will need a bit more information to properly assist.

Comment: Did you reboot your PC? Did you reboot your iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

The built in help (on Mac at least) doesn't have the good troubleshooting articles that http://support.apple.com does.

I would start with running a [Device Sync Test in iTunes](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4235) and if that won't even run, you can fall back to the [Device Connectivity Test](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1369).

That should pinpoint the source of the issue if it's not software to:

- OS issue
- USB hardware failure (on the computer, cable or device itself)
- Hardware failure of the device (get it repaired / restored by taking it to another computer)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had this problem with an iphone but I have with an ipod. To resolve I opened it on another machine. The other pc didn't think itunes was still open for it and so opened it up. When I went back to the original machine it worked fine again.

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting the iTunes Helper process in Task Manager. Otherwise reboot your device and your computer and that should take care of it.